# Generate Javadocs for struct

Tags: java, swig

I'm aware of the `%javamethodmodifiers` kludge to get Javadoc comments into generated Java code. For the most part, it works, but I am having no success getting it to work for getter/setter methods generated for a C struct. I've tried placing the `%javamethodmodifiers` before the struct definition, after it, etc. to no avail.

Is it possible to use `%javamethodmodifiers` to generate Javadoc comments for the class generated from a C struct?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
%typemap(javaclassmodifiers) class::enumname "/**
 * javadoc
 */
public enum";
```

this one i know is working for enums, but it may work for all objects that generate java side classes

also you can try standard rename:

```
%rename("/**
   * javadoc
   */
  ENUM_CONST")  class::ENUM_CONST;
```

this one is working for enum constants

Comment: I think the question was looking to document the gets/sets that are generated for members.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. Still, if there's no way to do that, then being able to generate documentation for the class is still helpful.

Comment: I was trying today, and only found nasty trick that may not fully work: when using swig for c++ you can add methods to struct (getter) and ignore original field.